# within Javascript executing curl batch file issues

Tags: javascript, curl, batch-file

I have a batch file that I am executing in a server side javascript file.  A batch file is created and saved off and then executed by the following statement:

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = oShell.Run(sWIPDirectory + "curl.bat", 0, true);
```

The batch file is as follows

\curlpath\curl -k -v -L --url "https://somesite.com/somepage?someParam=someValue&someParam2=someValue2%2BsomeMoreData%3D%3D&someParam3=someValue3" -o "\outputPath\outFile.pdf" --stderr \outPath\calloutput.txt

A problem occurs where the %2's and %3's are removed during execution.  I know batch scripts use these values as command line arguments however it shouldn't be happening when it is surrounded by quotation marks right?

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%2 and %3 will be replaced in a batch file, irrespective of quotes.  You should double them if you want to use them:

```
\curlpath\curl -k -v -L --url "https://somesite.com/somepage?someParam=someValue&someParam2=someValue2%%2BsomeMoreData%%3D%%3D&someParam3=someValue3" -o "\outputPath\outFile.pdf" --stderr \outPath\calloutput.txt
```

Comment: This does resolve my original issue but leads me to a new problem that I need to investigate.  Thanks for the quick and easy response!